# Onto homorphisms from $S_4$ to $S_2$

Tags: group-theory

Let $S_n$ represent the symmetric group on $n$ letters.

How can one find an onto homomorphism from $S_4$ to $S_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:  (1) Consider the sign of a permutation.  (2) What is the order of $S_2$?